# Replacing route with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, routes

I have the following nginx file that works and I have two urls `/us/api` and `/us/castle`. I would like to replace the `/us/castle/knights` with

`http://localhost:9000/us/castle/knights`

```
error_log /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/error.log;
pid /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx.pid;
worker_processes  1;
daemon off;
events { worker_connections  1024; }
http {
    access_log /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/access.log;
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        root /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/packages/castle-frontend/dist/site;
        location /us/api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
        location /us/castle {
            alias /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/packages/castle-frontend/dist/site;
            index index.dev.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.dev.htm =404;
            autoindex on;
            expires 0;
        }
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding this new `location`:

```
location /us/castle/knights {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/us/castle/knights
}
```

But it is not replacing this route specific.

So what I have is this, and it's not working:

```
error_log /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/error.log;
pid /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx.pid;
worker_processes  1;
daemon off;
events { worker_connections  1024; }
http {
    access_log /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/access.log;
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        root /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/packages/castle-frontend/dist/site;
        location /us/api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }
        location /us/castle/knights {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/us/castle/knights/;
        }
        location /us/castle {
            alias /Users/treggi/Projects/castle/packages/castle-frontend/dist/site;
            index index.dev.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.dev.htm =404;
            autoindex on;
            expires 0;
        }
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hit the nginx server I get a 502 error and the proxy_pass server itself is actually receiving the request and returning with 200 (from its server logs)

Comment: use `http://localhost:9000` as the value of `proxy_pass` in `location` block

Comment: @SALEH I just tried this and it's still giving me a 502.